# Multi-folds of Generating Functions

Tags: stochastic-processes, generating-functions

[Stochastic Process Generating Function Practice](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sCoXa.png)

I don't understand how $G_{N}(s) = G_{M}(G_{Y_i}(s))$.

$N = Y_1 + Y_2 + Y_3 + ... +Y_M$, which to my understanding the main generating function should be of $Y$ and the sub should be the index of $Y$. Therefore, I think $G_{N}(s) = G_{Y}(G_M(s))$. Am I wrong and if so, how to understand the correct version of the answer?

Comment: Please do not use pictures for critical portions of your post. Pictures may not be legible, cannot be searched and are not view-able to some, such as those who use screen readers.

Comment: The Wikipedia page on probability-generating functions explains why $G_{N}(s) = G_{M}(G_{Y}(s))$, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability-generating_function

Comment: That's exactly what I was looking for. Thank you so much!